# how can I Ignore truncation error on bulk insert

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, bulkinsert

Is there a way to ignore truncation?

If found this: https://www.sqlshack.com/sql-truncate-enhancement-silent-data-truncation-in-sql-server-2019/ but it doesn't work with bulk insert.

thanks!

Comment: Why not just make the column bigger? I can't imagine any valid business case for loading _some_ of the data.

Comment: It's more of a text field that makes no sense to use in a front end visualization, so I don't mind to truncate it.  I have gobs of fields that I do want to use in the file, so I just plainly want to load it.

Comment: So add a staging table that has that column (as a max), and then load the real table from the staging table _without that column at all_. I'd generally want to avoid directly bulk loading into a table used by front end users anyway.

Comment: I think there is a limitation.  Going to try again.  thank you for the suggestion, will update us.